# Transfer data between two database and check not repeated values synchronously

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want transfer some data between 2 tables from difference DBs But the source table have a some repeated values in `PostalCode` column, I create target table with UK on `PostalCode` column and in transfer script need to check synchronously to not insert a value that inserted before, this is my sample script:

```
INSERT INTO [Target]
(
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    [PostalCode],
)
(
SELECT  
[Sc].[FirstName],
[Sc].[LastName],
CASE 
WHEN 'Check for not repeated before' THEN [Sc].[PostalCode]
ELSE CAST(1000000000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Sc].[FirstName]) AS CHAR(10)) END

FROM [Source] AS [Sc]
);
```

So, what is your suggestion to handle this?

**Edit**

And is there any way to write an script with for or cursor? I mean check repeated Values asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend against mixxing two pieces of information into a single field.

Instead, just have an extra column, possibly called `DuplicationID`.

```
INSERT INTO [Target]
(
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    [PostalCode],
    [DuplicationID]
)
SELECT  
    [Sc].[FirstName],
    [Sc].[LastName],
    [Sc].[PostalCode],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Sc].[PostalCode] ORDER BY [Sc].[PostalCode])
FROM 
    [Soruce] AS [Sc]
```

Any record where DuplicationID is 1 is counted as the first instance of that postcode.  Any other value is a duplicate.

Comment: I try your answer and there is an error: `The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.`

Comment: @Saeid - You can add whetever ORDER BY you like.  I've added "PostalCode" which basically does nothing (If you partition by PostalCode, it will be the same for every record in the group, by definition).  You could decide to prioritise by LastName or any other field.  It just controls which gets DuplicateID 1, and which gets DuplicateID2, etc.  Play with it and see what is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [PostalCode]) AS NbrOf,
        ROW_Number() OVER
                    (
                        PARTITION BY [PostalCode] 
                        ORDER BY [PostalCode]
                ) AS RowNbr
        [FirstName],
        [LastName],
        [PostalCode],
    FROM
        [Source] AS [Sc]
)
INSERT INTO [Target]
(
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    [PostalCode],
)
SELECT  
    [Sc].[FirstName],
    [Sc].[LastName],
    CASE 
        WHEN CTE.NbrOf>1 
        THEN CAST(1000000000+CTE.RowNbr AS VARCHAR(10))
        ELSE [Sc].[PostalCode] 
    END
FROM 
    CTE
```